# node-red HTTP authentication through environmental variables

Tags: javascript, httprequest, node-red

I want to perform a GET request to an API but I want to make sure the endpoint, username and password are managed as environmental variabled because my node application will have multiple environments (dev/test/production).

I have added the environmental variables on the flow.
[image]

Now I'm trying to set the correct attributes on the `msg` object to replace the values with the environmental variables.
[image]

It's already working for the url but I'm not able to replace the username and password. I cannot find the correct attribute names anywhere in the docs.
I can imagine that a lot of people would have simular requirements when working with multiple-tier systems.

So what is in fact the correct way to achieve this?

```
msg.url = 
 env.get("MendixURL")
 + "/rest/shopfloorintegration/v1/message?PlantCode="
 + env.get("PlantCode");

msg.authentication = "basic";
msg.credentials = {
    username : env.get("MendixUsername"),
    password : env.get("MendixPassword")
};


return msg;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try and set them in the function node.

In the HTTP-Request node put `${MendixUsername}` in the Username field and `${MendixPassword}` in the Password filed.

e.g.

[image]

or you can encode username and password into the URL you are building in the function node.

e.g.

```
http://username:password@www.example.com/
```